# how could I fix this mistake of routes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm getting this warning and I can't see my routes except the "/" with contains "Default Page Content}" inside the App.js. How could i rewrite the code that contains the other routes ?

## Matched leaf route at location "/admin" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page

Im using :
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.2",

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch,Routes, Route,Swit } from 'react-router-dom';

import MasterLayout from '../src/assets/layouts/admin/MasterLayout'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
 <Router>
      
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<div>Default Page Content</div>}/>
        <Route  path="/admin" name="Admin" render={(props) => <MasterLayout {...props} />}/>  
        </Routes>
      
       
    </Router>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## Route.js

```
import Dashboard from '../assets/components/admin/Dashboard';
import Profile from '../assets/components/admin/Profile';


const routes = [
{path:'/admin',exact:true,name:'Admin'},
{path:'/admin/dashboard',exact:true,name:'Dashboard',component: Dashboard},
{path:'/admin/profile',exact:true,name:'Profile',component: Profile},

];


export default routes;
```

## MasterLayout.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Routes, Route, Swit } from 'react-router-dom';

import '../../admin/js/scripts.js'
import '../../admin/css/styles.css'

import Navbar from './Navbar.js';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar.js';
import Footer from './Footer.js';
import routes from '../../../routes/routes';



const MasterLayout = () => {

    return (
        <div className="sb-nav-fixed">
            <Navbar />
            <div id="layoutSidenav">
                <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                    <Sidebar />
                </div>
                <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                    <main>
                    <Router>
                        <Routes>
                            {routes.map((route, idx) => {

                                return (

                                    route.component && (

                                        <Route

                                            key={idx}
                                            path={route.path}
                                            exact={route.exact}
                                            name={route.name}
                                            render={(props) => (
                                                <route.component {...props} />
                                            )}
                                        />
                                    )

                                )

                            })}
                        </Routes>
                        </Router>
                        <Navigate from="/admin" to="/admin/dashboard"/>

                    </main>

                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>



    )
}

export default MasterLayout;
```

#Dashboard.js #

```
import React from 'react'

function Dashboard() {

    return (
        <h1>I am dashboard</h1>
    );

}

export default Dashboard;
```

## Profile.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Profile() {

    return (
        <h1>I am Profile</h1>
    );

}

export default Profile;
```

## Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Because as the warning states the route need an element. This might help: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/docs/upgrading/v5.md#advantages-of-route-element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` version 6 the `Route` component API changed significantly, there are no longer `component` or `render` props. They were replaced by the `element` prop that renders a JSX literal, not a reference to a React component or a function returning JSX.

> Matched leaf route at location "/admin" does not have an element. This
> means it will render an with a null value by default resulting in an
> "empty" page.

The `MasterLayout` component isn't being rendered as JSX on the `element` prop.

App

Fix how the `MasterLayout` component is rendered by the `Route`.

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<div>Default Page Content</div>} />
    <Route path="/admin/*" element={<MasterLayout />} />  
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

MasterLayout

Remove the extraneous `Router`, you need only one in the entire app. Render the `routes` into the `element` prop as JSX. Fix the redirect to be rendered into a `Route` on the `"/admin"` path within the `Routes`. The routes `MasterLayout` renders are relative from the parent `"/admin"` route, remove the `"/admin"` path prefix from the `routes` config.

```js
const routes = [
  { path: '/', exact: true, name: 'Admin' },
  { path: '/dashboard', exact: true, name: 'Dashboard', component: Dashboard},
  { path: '/profile', exact: true, name: 'Profile', component: Profile},
];
```

```
const MasterLayout = () => (
  <div className="sb-nav-fixed">
    <Navbar />
    <div id="layoutSidenav">
      <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
        <main>
          <Routes>
            {routes.filter(route => route.component)
              .map(({ path, component: Component }, idx) => (
                <Route
                  key={idx}
                  path={path}
                  element={<Component />}
                />
              ))}
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={<Navigate to="/admin/dashboard"/>}
            />
          </Routes>
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

An alternative solution using nested routes may look something like the following. The `MasterLayout` renders an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their element content into.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const MasterLayout = () => (
  <div className="sb-nav-fixed">
    <Navbar />
    <div id="layoutSidenav">
      <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
      <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
        <main>
          <Outlet />
        </main>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

App

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<div>Default Page Content</div>} />
    <Route path="/admin" element={<MasterLayout />}>
      {routes
        .filter(route => route.component)
        .map(({ path, component: Component }) => (
          <Route
            key={path}
            path={path}
            element={<Component />}
          />
        )
      )}
      <Route index element={<Navigate to="/admin/dashboard"/>} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 4):

React Router 6 gives us a very powerful feature (Nested Routes). This enables us to change URLs in the browser for different routes/links and instead of replacing the entire page only the content of the new tab/link gets replaced.
In order to use Nested Routes here, you can simply remove the Routes/routes.js file delete the import statement from App.js too and change your App.js file to the following

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import MasterLayout from './layouts/admin/MasterLayout';
import Dashboard from './components/admin/Dashboard';
import Profile from './components/admin/Profile';

    function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/admin" element={<MasterLayout />} > 
        <Route path='/admin/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />}/>
        <Route path='/admin/profile' element={<Profile />}/>
        </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Then add Outlet to the MasterLayout.js file in the following order to enable it render and replace it's content with the matching nested routes content.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Outlet, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import '../../assets/admin/css/styles.css';
import '../../assets/admin/js/scripts.js';

import Footer from './Footer';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';



const MasterLayout = ()=>{
    return (
        <div className="sb-nav-fixed">
            <Navbar/>

            <div id="layoutSidenav">
                <div id="layoutSidenav_nav">
                    <Sidebar/>
                </div>

                <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <main>
                    <Outlet/>
                    <Navigate from="admin" to="/admin/dashboard"/> 

                </main>
                <Footer/>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>

    );
}

export default MasterLayout;
```

I hope this helps those of us using the react-router-dom v-6 and above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/18304002/cardinal-paul thank you so much! Actually the key point is Outlet!